# Custom BaseAdapter getview get wrong positions android

Tags: java, android, listview, baseadapter

I know questions like this one was already asked but I went through all the solutions I saw and non has worked.
This is my adapter

```
class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Activity context;
    public Adapter(Activity context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Constants.CHARACTERS_NAMES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_charecter_item, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.PlayerName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                holder.PlayerName.setText(Constants.CHARACTERS_NAMES[position]);
                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
        return convertView;
    }
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView PlayerName;
    }
}
```

This is a standard adapter but when I debug it with my listview Instead of getting All my 7 items which are in Constants.CHARACTERS_NAMES I get the 4 first items right, but the I get the first item twice and then the second item.

Please help.

Comment: Move your holder.PlayerName stuff outside of your if/else statements and before returning convertView

Comment: Think about it for a minute. You were saying that if your convertView is null you want to create a holder, set the TextView for that holder, and then apply that holder as a tag to your view. If the convertView isn't null you just want to load the tag. That loads the holder that you have set as the tag and the associated TextView, but it doesn't modify the TextView. You have to modify the contents of your holder every time you get the view. The purpose of the holder is to minimize redundant view rendering.